# SQLite trigger optimization

Tags: sql, sqlite, optimization, triggers, query-optimization

This is a follow up based on [this question about query optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7334969/101969).

In order to make fast selection, as suggested, I tried to pre-compute some data at insertion time using a trigger.

Basically, I want to keep the number of occurrences of a given column's value into a given table.

The following schema is used to store the occurrences for each of the values:

```
CREATE TABLE valuecount (value text, count int)
CREATE INDEX countidx ON t (count DESC)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX valueidx ON valuecount (value);
```

And here is the trigger I've been testing with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER counttrigger INSERT ON collection
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      INSERT OR REPLACE INTO valuecount VALUES 
      (NEW.value, coalesce((SELECT count + 1 FROM count WHERE valuecount.query LIKE 
       NEW.value), 1));
    END;
```

A typical insertion on the `collection` table contains a few hundreds thousands of rows, in a single `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement (I'm merging data from a db to another).

The problem is that with this trigger, inserting 300K rows takes 4 hours, instead of 300 ms ...

Is there a way to achieve this without sacrificing performances?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: you might want to try an update where you join in NEW, followed by an INSERT of the SELECT FROM NEW where the rows don't exist.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't aware that [At this time SQLite supports only FOR EACH ROW triggers, not FOR EACH STATEMENT triggers.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).  In other databases I worked with they function on the `FOR EACH STATEMENT` scope, where you can do operations on the entire set of data that is changing.  I wasn't aware of this limitation of SQLite, so you can't do it how I was talking about in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it seemed that using a trigger wasn't a good idea afterall.

Since I'm merging a table from different databases, I did the upsert into the `valuecount` table based on the content of the table I'm merging, all in one statement, before the insert.

So instead of a trigger, I just have a query that looks like this, executed prior to my `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO valuecount
SELECT value, coalesce((SELECT count FROM valuecount WHERE valuecount.value = collection.value) + COUNT(value), COUNT(value))
FROM attached.collection GROUP BY value
```

Answer (score 2):

Since importing from one database to another is not as common a task as other inserts, can you defer the logic provided by the trigger until the import is complete? Looking at the nature of the trigger, it seems you could do a COUNT for each query type after all the data is imported. This would be significantly less queries overall.

If this is not possible, is there a way to avoid using LIKE? This operation is more expensive than a direct comparison.

Comment: I'm currently trying to do the COUNT before the insert (only on the 300K rows), and to insert the new counts at once. The COUNT can't be done on the whole db after it's been merged as it's taking way too much time (it needs to be fast even with hundreds millions of rows).